# How To Accept Payments By Check

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I have a client that will only be accepting payments by check at this time.  It is a larger company that has same clients and they bill the client and check is mailed.  However they want to be able to take orders online and I really wanted to try Craft Commerce.  What I need to do is somehow bypass the payment step.  I would like to be able to send them an invoice, but not one that says paid.  Any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

A pure ghetto method would be to just go into the pdf template and remove the "paid" markup.

I can't remember off hand, but I think it is just a div. Inspect the element to find the hook (id, class). Then either comment out the css rules or remove that element.

**EDIT**

It looks like this is the file you need to modify:

`/craft/templates/commerce/customer/order.html`

Comment: Hey Damon...thank you.  Worked perfect and was very simple.

Comment: Awesome - glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

The **Manual** payment gateway is designed for orders to be received without taking a live payment, or to be paid later by check or bank transfer. It allows you to mark the order as paid at a later time by clicking 'capture' in the order review screen.

Docs here: https://craftcommerce.com/docs/payment-gateways#manual-gateway

The manual gateway is included in the paid version of Craft Commerce.

Comment: First time I have ever used Craft Commerce.  My client is very specific about what he wants and I am currently working in the trial version to make sure it will do the job.  I used the dummy gateway, and still needed to add a credit card number to continue.  So with the paid version I will be able to not have the payment screen at all?

Comment: I love Commerce so far.  You did a great job working it with Craft.  Just have  an issue with variants.  Each product has five variants, but I only want one of those variants to show based upon currentUser.  Week and a half of searching and still cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: @user1663102 correct, the full version allows a simple: 'complete order' button with the manual payment method.